# Mi ciclo FOR da error cuando cambio el sentido del recorrido

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

mi codigo funcionaba bien, pero quiero ahora que la fila luego de ser copiada y pegada, elimine la fila.

Pensé en invertir el ciclo for y añadir "delete row" pero me da un error que no comprendo, si pudieran apoyarme a entender por favor.

```
  for (var i = oValues.length; i >0 ; i++) {
    if (matriz_Vencidos.includes(matriz_Total[i]) == false) {
      if (oValues[i][0] >= 10) {
        var Importante = sheet.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
        sheet_importante.getRange(sheet_importante.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, sheet_importante.getLastColumn()).setValues(Importante);
        sheet.deleteRow(i+2)
      }
    }
  }
```

El código anterior era:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < oValues.length ; i++) {
    if (matriz_Vencidos.includes(matriz_Total[i]) == false) {
      if (oValues[i][0] >= 10) {
        var Importante = sheet.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
        sheet_importante.getRange(sheet_importante.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, sheet_importante.getLastColumn()).setValues(Importante);
      }
    }
  }
```

El error que me arroja es

> 

14:23:59    Aviso   Se ha iniciado la ejecución
14:24:00    Error
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
SettingImportanteDiferente  @ Código.gs:74

> 

La línea 74 es la de

```
      if (oValues[i][0] >= 10) {
```

Comment: La matriz es simétrica?

Comment: en tu primer código... tienes `i++` no debería ser `i--`? Por eso saca el error, porque i empieza en la longitud del array y luego le vas sumando +1... tienes es que restarle.

Comment: @FranAcuna Disculpa, no comprendo qué significa que sea simétrica. La que tengo es una matriz de valores de un mismo tipo (INT) 

El oValues recoge los elementos de una columna, por eso tiene valores [i][0]
La verdad que cuando intenté el for con i++ sí funcionaba, pero cambié a i-- y me salió el problema. Si pudieras ayudarme a entender estaría muy agradecido

Comment: @Pipe Sí, es que lo que pasa es que en el primer trozo de código intenté recorrer de arriba hacia abajo, para el segundo intenté voltear la situación y recorrer de abajo hacia arriba. 
Como quiero borrar, si pongo el deleterow() cuando es bucle de arriba a abajo no se eliminan correctamente los valores porque i cambia con cada eliminación.

Answer (score 0):

Tus for no recorren los mismo valores.

```
for (var i = oValues.length; i >0 ; i++)
```

Lo primero es que haces i++, para recorrer a la inversa hay que hacer i--

```
for (var i = oValues.length; i >0 ; i--)
```

Digamos que tienes 10 elementos
Aquí i tomaría los valores de: 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1

Y en el otro for

```
for (var i = 0; i < oValues.length ; i++)
```

Aquí i tomaría los valores de: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9